# Refresh the page on a browser resize using JavaScript when difference is more than 100px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code from website
[jQuery refresh page on browser resize](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-refresh-page-browser-resize/)
Works fine but its too sensitive on mobile devices.
So i shoud add some margin of error.
How tu use this code when difference in browser width is more than 100px
if browser width is smaller and larger

```html
//refresh page on browser resize
$(window).bind('resize', function(e)
{
  if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
  window.RT = setTimeout(function()
  {
    this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
  }, 200);
});
```

Comment: `if($(window).width() < 100) // do code` ?

Comment: Deciding to add a margin of error is a bit of a stab in the dark - you're going to end up leaving a single user or group of users out. What are you trying to achieve that needs to change for small screens? If it's simply the layout (or something like that) you want to change, design and build for any size - you can't safely guarantee when a browser should be called 'mobile'.

Comment: Seems weird that you would refresh the page on resize.

Comment: May I ask why would you reload? There may be a better solution to your problem than just reloading the page!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "when difference in browser width is more than 100px" means you're attempting to detect that the window has changed in size by more than 100px.   To do this you'll need to store the original width of the window and compare against that:

```
var originalWidth = $(window).width();
$(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
  if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
  window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
    if (Math.abs($(window).width() - originalWidth) > 100) {
      this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
    }
  }, 200);
});
```

(This seems an odd requirement, however: refreshing the page on window resize is far from ideal UX. You may find it better to use CSS breakpoints, or scripting if necessary, to modify the page in place rather than the brute-force approach of reloading the whole thing.)

Answer (score 0):

Store

```
var currentWidth = $( window ).width() to a temporary variable.
```

After resizing, check the difference

```
( currentWidth - $(window).width() ) > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let currentWidth = $(window).width();
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            if(($(window).width() - currentWidth ) > 100 || (currentWidth - $(window).width()) > 100 )  {
                currentWidth = $(this).width();
                location.reload();
            }
        });
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.